# Create a trigger for a table whose values are dependent on another table

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have a hospital database and in that database I have an `Appointments` table and a `Visits` table. In the `Appointments` table I have a column named `Validation` that can have values 0 and 1.

I want to create a trigger that doesn’t let someone insert a record into the `Visits` table if the value of the `Validation` column is 0. How would I go about that?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I need to verify that Validation column at Appointments Table has value “1” before inserting on Visits Table. Can I do that with trigger or with anything else ?

Comment: You can do it with a trigger or with something else. Next.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to implement the sought-for restriction without a trigger, using declarative statements only.

I am assuming you have an `AppointmentID` column in the `Appointments` table that is the table's primary key.  And I am also assuming that the `Visits` table has a reference column pointing to that PK. For the purposes of this answer, I am assuming the foreign key column is also called `AppointmentID`.

In other words, the assumption is that the two tables are defined something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Appointments
(
  AppointmentID int NOT NULL,
  Validation bool NOT NULL,
  ... /* other columns*/
  PRIMARY KEY (AppointmentID)
);

CREATE TABLE Visits
(
  VisitID int NOT NULL,
  AppointmentID int NOT NULL,
  ... /* other columns*/
  PRIMARY KEY (VisitID),
  FOREIGN KEY (AppointmentID) REFERENCES Appointments (AppointmentID)
);
```

Now if you define `(AppointmentID, Validation)` as a unique key in the `Appointments` table:

```
UNIQUE (AppointmentID, Validation)
```

you will make that pair of column referable from other tables.

The next step would be to add a column called `Validation` to the `Visits` table and make sure that that column always has the value of 1. The best option would be to define `Validation` as a generated column that has a constant value of 1:

```
Validation bool AS (1)
```

And then you would define the foreign key like this:

```
FOREIGN KEY (AppointmentID, Validation)
REFERENCES Appointments (AppointmentID, Validation)
```

However, since you are using MySQL, you cannot use this method, because MySQL does not (still, as of v8.0) support generated columns in foreign keys. And because of that I would suggest that you consider switching to MariaDB, which is very similar to MySQL and *does* support foreign keys consisting of generated columns.

However, there is still hope that you are at least using MySQL 8 or later version, because in that case you have an alternative: a regular (not generated) `Validation` column but with a check constraint that ensures that you cannot insert into that column anything other than 1. Something like this:

```
Validation bool NOT NULL,
...
CHECK (Validation = 1)
```

And then add the same foreign key definition as above:

```
FOREIGN KEY (AppointmentID, Validation)
REFERENCES Appointments (AppointmentID, Validation)
```

Now you will not be able to insert a row into `Visits` referencing an appointment unless that appointment is validated (i.e. has `Validation` set to 1). Note also that once you have added a row to `Visits`, you would also be unable to invalidate the referenced appointment, i.e. you cannot set its `Validation` value to 0. The foreign key will protect you from causing inconsistency in both cases.

Here are two demo fiddles – one for MariaDB, with a generated column, and another for MySQL, with a check constraint – to illustrate the approach:

- [generated column](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=eb8fc824ff94c03db8568e848883dbee)
- [check constraint](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=31528c13b317dce3685df0617a1b6fbe)

Obviously, the second variation is inferior to the first one because you have to explicitly specify a value for `Visits.Validation` at every insert. I would still consider it a small price to pay, though, since in return you are getting data consistency defined with no procedural code but purely declaratively.

Answer (score -1):

Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7189396/5059085) of how to create a `BEFORE INSERT` **trigger** that throws an error.

If your version of MySQL is at least version 8 then you can also look into creating a [`CHECK CONSTRAINT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) with a [**user-defined function**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-function-udf.html) that checks the `Appointments` table's `Validation` column.

Comment: So you are saying to create a user defined function that checks if validation column on Appointments table, then that function to call on Check Constraint at Visits table

Comment: @unidentified Yes, that's one solution I was saying using `CHECK CONSTRAINT`.